# What does "put on " mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, verbs, adjectives, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the Woody Allen film "Annie Hall"

(Alvy) *... Alvy Singer.  I'm a comedian.*

(ALLISON)- *Oh, comedian.  Yes.  Oh, uh ... you're on next.*

(ALVY)- *What do you mean, next?*

(ALLISON)- *Uh ... I mean you're on right after
this act.*

(ALVY)- *No, it can't be, because he's a comic.*

(ALLISON)- *Yes.*

(ALVY)- *So what are you telling me, you're **putting on** two comics in a row?*

**"on" adj**

a. performing, as on stage: *I'm on in five minutes.*(Collins Dictionary)

**"on" adj**

40. performing or broadcasting: *The radio announcer told us we were on*.(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

**"put" verb**

2. to cause to be (in a state, relation, etc): *to put one's things in order.*(Collins Dictionary)

Is this a combination of the verb "put" and the adjective "on" Which can be rephrased **"causing to be performing on the stage""**? Or perhaps, it's this phrasal verb:

**"put on" phrasal verb**

9. To make someone or something available for listening to, talking to, or watching via some broadcast or communication medium: *Let's put on some music while we work. Will you put your mother on the phone?*(The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.)

Comment: You have it - "causing to be performing on the stage"

Comment: Yes, put two comics on the stage to do their act in the same evening.

Comment: @Lambie I think it's worse than that, put two comics on the stage one after the other without an intervening act.